# WPF expander size issue

Tags: wpf, size, controls, expander

I am using an `ItemsControl` to place n number of `Expander`s. My `ItemsControl` will be placed in a `Grid` with height 600 (for example). I want to make sure my `ItemsControl` will always occupy the entire available `Height`, to do so it can expand some of the `Expander`s.

What will be the best approach to do so?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to bind the `Height` and `Width` properties of your control to the parent's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties